# Probability: what is the probability that 2 out of 7 people get three 6s when rolling 4 dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 7 students each roll 4 dice, what is the probability that 2 out of seven students roll exactly three 6s?

my first instinct was to do (1/6 * 1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6) then multiply it by 7 choose 2, but I don't know if I'm doing this right.

Comment: No, there are a number of things wrong with this.  First, $\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$ is the probability that you roll a six *and then* roll a six *and then* roll a six *and then* roll a not-six *in that very specific order*.  You neglected to account for the other orders it could have happened.  Once you have that probability, we'll call it $p$... you went on to multiply by $\binom{7}{2}$... that is a fine start but you forgot to do everything else that is needed for a binomial distribution... namely you forgot to take $p$ to a power and also use $(1-p)$'s

Comment: Look again at the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  This problem has you use it twice.  First to find the probability a particular individual actually gets three 6's, and again using that earlier found probability as your $p$ to find that $2$ of your $7$ students actually achieved such a roll.

Comment: Following @JMoravitz: In R, code `p = dbinom(3, 4, 1/6); dbinom(2, 7, p)`
returns $0.00462698.$ (That's for _exactly_ 3 `6`s, and _exactly_ 2 students.) This is not a problem where normal approximations will work well.

Comment: The probability to get three 6s out of $4$ is $p=\binom{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\frac56$.  For the number $X$ out of seven students rolling exactly three 6s use a binomial with $n=7$ and the computed $p$ above, that is $$\binom{7}{2}p^2(1-p)^5.$$